# Proof: $a = x^2 - y^2, x - y > 1 \implies a$ is not a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble doing a proof on the subject:

$a = x^2 - y^2, x - y > 1 \implies a$ is not a prime number.

$a, x, y \in Z$

The book has not yet introduced the theory of congruences, so it should be a 'fairly' simple proof i guess ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hint: Do you know how to factor $x^2 - y^2$?

Comment: Hint - your original title with $x-y\gt 0$ was incorrect, but the statement in the body of the question is correct.

Comment: he is saying x-y>1 so it's fine

Comment: @Jam My comment is a hint as to what the important fact might be, not an answer. And as my comment on your original answer illustrates, it is the key fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$

if $x-y$ is not zero and $x+y$ is not zero and $(x-y)>1$ so is $(x+y)$

then $x^2-y^2$ is divisible by both $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ so it is not prime number

my concern is he doesn't mention if both $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers if they are not then this claim would be not correct

Comment: You seem to be answering the version in the original title, where the claim is not actually correct.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft For example $16-9=7$

Comment: he mentions x-y>1 and that means what you are asking is not right

Comment: 4^2-3^2=(4-3)*(4+3) in your explanation 4-3=1 but in his question x-y>1 so the proof is fine

Comment: My comment was because you did not in the original version of this answer use that fact or even mention it.

Comment: cool i added more explanation

Comment: But you only say that $x-y$ is not zero. Suppose $x-y=1$, and say $a=4^2-3^2=7$. The  your argument, as it stands, does not work. EDIT: Sorry, too late.

Comment: i know i didn't type x-y>1 before sorry i am not very good at writing answers properly here yet